# Can I add hide/show list to my Quick launch links

Tags: 2013, javascript, css, quick-launch

I have parent/child links hierarchy inside my Quick Launch links, but is there a way to be able to hide/show the child links, instead of always showing the child links?

**::EDIT::**
I have modified my master page as follow :-

```
<SharePoint:AspMenu id="V4QuickLaunchMenu" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" DataSourceId="QuickLaunchSiteMap" UseSimpleRendering="true" Orientation="Vertical" StaticDisplayLevels="1" AdjustForShowStartingNode="true" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="1" SkipLinkText="" />
```

and currently i will have a menu for displaying the child links, but the look&feel for the menu is not that much impressive , and the child links will be shown as if they are on a seperate box as follow:-
[image]

so is there a way to improve the look and feel for the menu ?
Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the Quick Launch Navigation control and set Static Display Level, Dynamic Display Level properties

PS: It was this way in SP 2010, I hope its the same in 2013

Comment: it seems the same on SP2013, but the look and feel for the generated menu is not correct. can you check my Edit please ?

Comment: don't know about that !

Comment: another issue added to the list for SharePoint 2013 !, and not mentioning what will happen if i chnage the Orientation="Vertical" to Horizantal !!

Comment: well it will display menu items horizontally rather than vertically (horizontally like the top navigation items)